# How to pass data contained in dynamic bootstrap modal to the controller in Spring Boot application to be able to do required POST operations?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a bootstrap modal wrapped inside a form tag.

```
<form method = "POST" th:action = "@{/ProcessRequest}">
//Long Bootstrap modal code inside this form. At the end I have two action (POST) buttons as:
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-background btn-sm" name = "action" value="Approve" />
<input type="submit" id="reject" class="btn btn-background btn-sm" name = "action" value="Reject" />
```

I have table in my front end and this bootstrap modal is triggered by clicking on the rightmost field/column in that table.

```
<tr th:each="manObj : ${manObj}">
    <td th:text="${manObj.requestId}" title="Requestd ID"></td>
    <td th:text="${manObj.requestor}" title="Requestor"></td>
    <td th:text="${manObj.commodity}" title="Commodity"></td>
    <td th:text="${manObj.effectiveDate}" title="Input Date">
    <td title="Approve Request"><a th:href = "@{findOne/(requestId=${manObj.requestId},requestLineNbr=${manObj.requestLineNbr})}" 
    class = "btn btn-primary eBtn">
            <img src="./images/approver_menu.png" width="12px" height="12px"></img>
        </a></td>
</tr>
```

I am binding the object in each table row and the modal by using jquery to store this object in a variable `href` and then populating the modal like this:

```
$('.tableA').on('click','.eBtn',function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#confirmViewRequest').modal('show');  
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   $.get(href,function(manObj,status){
        $('.myform #requestId').html(manObj.requestId);
        $('.myform #effectiveDate').html(manObj.effectiveDate);
        $('.myform #expirationDate').html(manObj.expirationDate);
        $('.myform #commodity').html(manObj.commodity);
        $('.myform #discount').html(manObj.discount);
        $('.myform #address1').html(manObj.address1);
        $('.myform #city').html(manObj.city);
        $('.myform #state').html(manObj.state);
    });
```

I have methods in my controller where I need the values stored in this dynamic bootstrap model so that I can do necessary backend actions. BUT i do not know how to fetch the `requestId` to the controller once user clicks on that `Approve` button. Right now I have my controller as:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/ProcessRequest",params = "action=Approve")
public String ApproveRequest() {

    //Need to fetch requestId here so that I can do necessary actions

    //Integer requestId = Integer.parseInt(requestIdStr);

    //ip1requestCustom.changeStatus(requestId); 
    //System.out.println("All status changed for"+requestId);
    return "home";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/ProcessRequest",params = "action=Reject")
public String RejectRequest() {
    //Same. need that requestId from dynamic bootstrap modal
    return "home";
}
```

I need either the value stored in `'requestId'` or the object in my controller. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using `<input>` tag instead of `<span>` tag in the modal. Then I gave `name` attribute to the `<input>` tag for those dynamic data. I then used `RequestParam` to get the value contained in that field. In a nutshell, I did this to my controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/ProcessRequest",params = "action=Approve")
public String ApproveRequest(@RequestParam Map<String,String> reqPar) {
    String requestId = reqPar.get("requestId");     
    System.out.println(requestId);
    return "home";
}
```